# svg blobbed image is broken after encoding it

Tags: svg, encoding, blob

I've tried parsing an image into blob and refer it in `image` tag in svg:

```
`<image xlink:href="${imgRef}" height="${h}" width="${w}" stroke="red" x="50%" y="50%" transform="translate(${-(w / 2)}, ${-(h / 2) - 4})"/>`
```

and embed it in svg:

```
const w = 100; // width
const h = 65; // height

const svgString = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">` +
`<image xlink:href="${imgRef}" height="${h}" width="${w}" stroke="red" x="50%" y="50%" transform="translate(${-(w / 2)}, ${-(h / 2) - 4})"/>` +
`</svg>`;
```

Then I tried encoding it through `'data:image/svg+xml;,' + encodeURIComponent(svgString)` and it shows a broken image. I tested the above svg string before encoding it via `document.body.innerHTML = svgString` and the svg image is well displayed. So I'm suspecting the encoding part but it doesn't seem wrong based on many references.

What am I missing? Any insight would be appreciated.

Demo link: https://codepen.io/Dongbin/pen/poRmbmg?editors=0010

Comment: Obviously the string you posted can not have been injected as is, because `${w}` etc are not valid attribute values.  So what are you actually passing to `encodeURIComponent()`?

Comment: Also, you seem to have a stray semicolon in `'data:image/svg+xml,'`.  Try removing it.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau `w` and `h` are width and height. I updated the post. Plus, the semicolon is a syntax, which is not wrong

Comment: when you say "I've tried encodinng it' did you mean the svgString or the image xlink:href value. You need to url encode the image's xlink:href value.

Comment: I meant the `svgString`. `'data:image/svg+xml;,' + encodeURIComponent(svgString)`

Comment: @RobertLongson You mean I need to url-encode the `<image>` field alone? Not the whole svgString?

Comment: If you URI encode `svgString`, it works in Firefox (`newImg.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(svgString)}';
`).  It doesn't work in Chrome though, so that seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External images (ie `<img>` or CSS `background-image`) **must be self contained**.  They cannot refer to resources outside the image itself.  Basically that means if you need to reference any files (bitmap images, fonts, etc) as part of the SVG image, they need to be Data URLs.

The fix is to not use `canvas.toBlob()`.  Use `canvas.toDataURL()` instead.

```
const imgRef = canvas.toDataURL();
const svgString = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" ` +
                    `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">` +
                    `<image xlink:href="${imgRef}" height="125" width="200"/>` +
                  `</svg>`;
```

**Update**

If you URI Encode the SVG, it should work.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/dxkeqfnr/

```js
const img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://live.staticflickr.com/7272/7633179468_3e19e45a0c_b.jpg';
img.crossOrigin="anonymous"
img.onload = () => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 200;
  canvas.height = 125;
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 125);
  
  canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
    const imgRef = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const svgString = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="125" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><image xlink:href="${imgRef}" height="125" width="200"/></svg>`;
    
    //div.innerHTML = svgString;
    const newImg = new Image();
    newImg.src = `data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(svgString)}`;
    document.body.appendChild(newImg);
  });
};
```

It works in Firefox, but it doesn't work in Chrome. That seems to be a bug.  [I have reported the bug to Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1204490)

Comment: I used `canvas.toDataURL()` before but the reason I chose to change it to `canvas.toBlob()` is that it caused a performance issue. And as far as I know, URL.createObjectURL(blob) could work the same as `.toDataURL()`. Is it wrong?

Comment: I've noticed the related issue was reported 6 years ago in chrome but nothing seems to have been progressed about it. Would there be any workaround for this?

Comment: Best I can think of is to fall back to using data urls in Blink (Chrome-based) browsers.